# WPF how to prevent focus wrap on several buttons?

Tags: wpf, button, focus

I am curious if anyone knows if it is possible to prevent "focus wrap" on a series of buttons.  If I merely add a few buttons to a grid within WPF like so:

```
<Window x:Class="ButtonList_Test.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:ButtonList_Test"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800">
    <StackPanel x:Name="myStackPanel" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center">
        <Grid x:Name="myGrid">
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"></ColumnDefinition>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"></ColumnDefinition>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"></ColumnDefinition>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"></ColumnDefinition>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"></ColumnDefinition>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="*"></RowDefinition>
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>

            <Button Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0">A</Button>
            <Button Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0">B</Button>
            <Button Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="0">C</Button>
            <Button Grid.Column="3" Grid.Row="0">D</Button>
            <Button Grid.Column="4" Grid.Row="0">E</Button>

        </Grid>
    </StackPanel>
</Window>
```

And run the program, it will produce 5 small buttons in a nice single row.

[image: 5 buttons in a row]

If I click on the button in the middle (C), and then start to use any of the keyboard arrow keys, you will notice that the focus will begin to traverse these buttons in the direction of the key you are pressing.

If the dotted line reaches the "E" button, and I press one more time to the right, it will wrap back to the "A" button.

Is there any way to prevent this functionality?

Thank you in advance for any insight you may be willing to provide,

Answer (score 0):

You can try `Focusable="False"`. As far as I know, traverse controls with arrow keys or Tab keys can be happened by group of `Focusable="True"` controls only.

For example, if you try

```
<Button Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0">A</Button>
<Button Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0">B</Button>
<Button Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="0" Focusable="False">C</Button>
<Button Grid.Column="3" Grid.Row="0">D</Button>
<Button Grid.Column="4" Grid.Row="0">E</Button>
```

and click B then press right key, D will be focused. So if you want to prevent every traverse, you can set `Focusable="False"` to every Buttons.

Comment: Thanks Ryu for taking the time to respond.  This is not an exact solution to my issue, as I do want the buttons to be Focasable, just not when they can wrap around.  However, using this information, it may be possible to calculate when to toggle the Focusable to False when you don't want the wrap around, and back to True when you do.  Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

Set the `IsTabStop` property of all buttons to `false` or define an implicit `Style` that sets this property for all buttons:

```
<StackPanel x:Name="myStackPanel" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center">
    <Grid x:Name="myGrid">
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"></ColumnDefinition>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"></ColumnDefinition>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"></ColumnDefinition>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"></ColumnDefinition>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"></ColumnDefinition>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"></RowDefinition>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Grid.Resources>
            <Style TargetType="Button">
                <Setter Property="IsTabStop" Value="False" />
            </Style>
        </Grid.Resources>

        <Button Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0">A</Button>
        <Button Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0">B</Button>
        <Button Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="0">C</Button>
        <Button Grid.Column="3" Grid.Row="0">D</Button>
        <Button Grid.Column="4" Grid.Row="0">E</Button>

    </Grid>
</StackPanel>
```

Comment: Thanks mm8 for taking the time to respond.  Similar to Ryu's answer, this is not an exact solution.  I do want the buttons to be focusable, but just not when the focus would wrap around to the other side.  I could though likely however use this information to calculate when I want certain buttons to have IsTabStop to True, and other times when it would be False.  Thanks again.